# why the `test process` is inside the epoch loop in deep learning?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, neural-network, pytorch, training-data

I am new to deep learning, here is the [code](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py) I saw

The code is fine, but I don't understand the follow:

```
for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
    train(epoch)
    test(epoch)
    with torch.no_grad():
        sample = torch.randn(64, 20).to(device)
        sample = model.decode(sample).cpu()
```

In machine learning, when we finish training, we fix the model parameters for the test dataset. here are my two questions:

(1) In deep learning, we have the training, validation, test dataset. Is the code `test(epoch)` actually for validation set?  There we fix model parameters and predict for test dataset `outside the epoch loop`?

(2) what is `with torch.no_grad():` mean? and why it also inside the `epoch loop`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the `test(epoch)` is actually for validation here *(Update: not exactly validation, check below answer)*.
2. `with torch.no_grad()` means that you're switching off the gradients (required for backpropagation during training). In validation/testing you don't need them, and it'll save memory and computations. Read more [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/32654/30543).

Also, check the [tutorial here](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/master/intro-to-pytorch/Part%205%20-%20Inference%20and%20Validation%20(Solution).ipynb).

Comment: Thanks a lot. since `test(epoch)` is for validation. Why not `with torch.no_grad():  test(epoch)`?  I mean switching off the gradients for `test(epoch)`

Comment: Check the [`test(epoch)`](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/ee964a2eeb41e1712fe719b83645c79bcbd0ba1a/vae/main.py#L106) function, it too has it.

Comment: Now I understand the `with torch.no_grad()` in `test(epoch)`.   The second `with torch.no_grad():  sample = torch.randn(64, 20).to(device)` is it for test dataset? why it is insider the `epoch loop`?

Comment: Yes, for testing, a random torch tensor is passed to the model here. I think it's inside the for loop so as to compare the output after every epoch (it simply saves the image after every epoch).

Answer (score 1):

1. In the example that you shared, there is no validation. Usually, we perform validation to identify if the model improved from the last epoch and save a checkpoint. In this example, authors perform training and testing without any validation check.
2. `with torch.no_grad()` basically disable the gradient computation. Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference when you are sure that you will not call `Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory consumption for computations.
3. Why inside the `epoch` loop, they perform decoding using a random sample? This is just to see a visualization of the generated image from a random sample. Please note, the `test(epoch)` function gives you quantitative value which tells you how well the model performs. However, the image generation is intended for qualitative comparison, i.e., how the model improves image generation with each epoch.